# The attribute connectionstringName is missing or empty

Tags: asp.net

I am getting this exception when trying to get or create a user using Membership or Profile.Here is my web.config code.I am using VS2010 Framework 4.0.

What could be the problem?

```
    <connectionStrings>
    <add name="classConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=MINHAS\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Test;Integrated Security=True"/>
</connectionStrings>
    <profile defaultProvider="MyProvider">
        <properties>
            <add name="Name" type="System.String"/>
            <add name="ID" type="System.String"/>
            <add name="Color" type="System.String"/>
        </properties>
        <providers>
            <clear/>
            <add name="MyProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connnectionStringName="classConnectionString" applicationName="/"/>
        </providers>
    </profile>
    <membership defaultProvider="MyProvider">
        <providers>
            <add name="MyProvider" connnectionStringName="classConnectionString" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" applicationName="/" enablePasswordRetrieval="true" enablePasswordReset="true" passwordFormat="Encrypted" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true"/>
        </providers>
    </membership>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have given three times n in connection string name

```
connnectionStringName="classConnectionString"
```